# how to make a button work only when click in a specific area?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a button with a transparent image set and I would like to make the click work only when the drawn part is clicked and not the transparent one.

As I don't understand how to change the shape of the Button object, I thought to insert in front of the image items that went to cover the transparent part (also then they will be set transparent) so that clicking at those points, these items were clicked instead of the button and the click was not detected.

[screenshot design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMKkD.png)

I tried doing it this way but even clicking on the ImageView, it feels like it's clicking the button.

how can I do?

**.xml**

```js
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btClick"
    android:layout_width="266dp"
    android:layout_height="350dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvShow" />
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="103dp"
    android:layout_height="43dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
    android:elevation="9999px"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/btClick"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/btClick"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/btClick"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/btClick"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="101dp"
    android:layout_height="242dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
    android:elevation="9999px"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/btClick"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/btClick"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/btClick"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/btClick"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_width="91dp"
    android:layout_height="245dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
    android:elevation="9999px"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/btClick"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/btClick"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/btClick"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/btClick"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_width="114dp"
    android:layout_height="44dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
    android:elevation="9999px"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/btClick"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/btClick"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/btClick"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/btClick"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
imageView.bringToFront()
imageView.setEnabled(false)
```

`bringToFront()` to make sure `ImageView` covers your button and then don't allow to interact with it by `setEnabled(false)`

Answer (score 0):

`android:clickable="false"` just add this code in ImageView

Example

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="103dp"
        android:layout_height="43dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        android:elevation="9999px"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/btClick"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/btClick"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/btClick"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/btClick"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        android:clickable="false"/>
```